# How to map JSP file in Spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, jsp, gradle, java-11

This is my first spring boot application. I want to load home.jsp file in 8080 port.
When I run port 8080/home I can see home.jsp file is download. How I run that home.jsp

**Bellow you can see my HomeController.Java file**

```
  package com.example.demo;
    
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
    
    @Controller
    public class HomeController {
        
        @RequestMapping("home")
        public String Home()
        {
            System.out.print("Hello");
            return "home.jsp";
        }
    }
```

**Bellow you can see my home.jsp file**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
  I love Java
</body>
</html>
```

**Bellow you can see my gradle.build file**

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.6.0'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'

}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    classpath('se.transmode.gradle:gradle-docker:1.2')
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jasper:9.0.55'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    

    
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Here I added tomcat dependency

Comment: Your `JSP` file is into your WEB-INF?

Comment: No i created folder named webapp inside the src/main. JSP file path is src/main/webapp. But when run the program auto download jsp file

Comment: but real path is `src/main/resources/templates`

Comment: The JSP view engine is tightly coupled with the web server. It depends on libraries that a provided by the web server and not by the web app. So it's more complex to set it up correctly. See https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-jsp for a good intro.

Comment: I created this project by maven using same codes. Its working properly. I think problem is in the build.gradle file. I added here dependency of tomcat in build.gradle I think that is not working

Comment: Have you considered using a more modern templating language instead of JSP? Eg [freemarker](https://freemarker.apache.org/)

Comment: @lance-java will try

Answer (score 0):

application.yml

```
server.port=8080
  
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/view/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

try adding the followings in gradle then update gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    runtime('com.h2database:h2')
    runtime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')
    compileOnly('org.projectlombok:lombok')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

ohh and add
'/' in front of the requestmapping

```
 @Controller
    public class HomeController {
        
        @RequestMapping("/home")
        public String Home()
        {
            System.out.print("Hello");
            return "home.jsp";
        }
    }
```